# How to slide a texture horizontally accross a sphere with threejs

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 360 viewer.

I want to load a texture in a specific position that rotates the original texture 
a number of degrees or Y units around without affecting how the picture shows up other than the rotation.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a pattern you can follow if you want to rotate your texture around the y-axis of your sphere:

```
var loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();

var texture = loader.load( 'path.jpg', function ( texture ) {

    texture.wrapS = THREE.RepeatWrapping;
    texture.offset.set( degrees / 360, 0 );

} );
```

three.js r.91

Comment: I actually found this on my own and forgot to come back and check here.  sorry about that.

Comment: That's even a better way! :)